# Windows 10 IoT Raspberry Pi 2: Does .NET have mouse support as well?

Tags: .net-framework-version, windows-10, raspberry-pi2

I just managed to deploy my first Windows IoT Core (Background Application IoT) and Windows Universal (Blank App) via VS 2015 on RasPI2. After a quick scan I wonder if there is any mouse handling (MouseMove ...) integrated in the new .Net framework as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what google was able to tell me, the answer is yes. You're app cannot be headless (so have UI and a screen, which makes sense). Here is the example I was able to find. It seems like movement is constrained to a Xaml UI object.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerpressed

Answer (score 4):

They're not in the .Net Framework: they're in the Windows Runtime.

Pointer events ([PointerPressed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerpressed.aspx), [PointerMoved](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointermovedevent.aspx), [PointerReleased](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerreleased.aspx), etc.) are part of the Universal app contract and available on all Windows devices, including IoT.

Pointer events cover all pointer devices including mouse, touch, pen.